# enable webrtc in Google Chrome

Tags: mac, google-chrome

I'm using an open source application that requires a browser with Webrtc. I have been able to use it with Google Chrome, however, after clearing all of the following data, I get notifications from the application that I need Webrtc.

```
Clear browsing history

Clear download history

Delete cookies and other site and plug-in data

Empty the cache
```

Is there a way to enable Webrtc in Chrome after it somehow became disabled? I'm using a Mac

Comment: Type `Chrome://flags` in address bar(Omnibox) and hit enter then use search option and see if WebRTC is enable or disable there.

Comment: WebRTC is mentioned 11 times on the page but I can't tell if it clearly says it's enabled or disabled

Comment: But its only 2 times where is has option to enable or disable otherwise it is saying something about your platform.